# Firebase Database Rules: different rule for parent and child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have my database like this:

[image: Firebase Rules ScreenShot]

*user123* is an admin. Hence he should be able to loop through all nodes in **entries**. Others cannot see child of **entries** unless *uid* of entryID is *auth.uid*

How shall I set rules for this? If there is no possible way, any suggestion to change dataBase :)

Answer (score 2):

if you already know admin is, in your question user123. Then you database rule should be like

```
"entities": { 
  "$entryId":{
      // you don't what others to see other to see teh data
    ".read": "auth.uid == 'user123'"
      // any one who is logged in should write to the /entries node
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

In case you what to make the rule more dynamic then you can do

```
"entities": {
  "$entityId":{
      // you don't what others to see other to see teh data
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true || root.child('entities').child($entityId).child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
      // any one who is logged in should write to the /entries node
      ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

You can get more info from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/

Alternatively, You can change your entries model to user specific

```
{
  "entities" :{
     "user465": {
       "entry456": {
         "text" : "Some sample text"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

In this case, you write you rule

```
"entities": {
  "$userId":{
     // you don't what others to see other to see teh data
     ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true || $userId == auth.uid"
     // any one who is logged in should write to the /entries node
     ".write": "auth.uid == $userId"
  }
}
```

Comment: The rule is dynamic. With this rule, user who made the entry cannot read it. For example, 'user123' should be able to read 'entry456'

Comment: @Nameer see the updated answer, you can change your entries model as well.

Comment: But admin cannot loop through all the entries, it shows 'Permission Denied' Error.

Comment: @npk You can add an extra rule; if one rule denies then rules below will be checked.